# Cognos 10.2 - date range default earliest vs today

Tags: cognos-10

Very simple question (hopefully) but I can't find the answer anywhere. I have two seemingly identical date prompts for optional date ranges. One defaults to today's date. The other defaults to 'earliest' and 'latest'. But I can't for the life of me find the setting that controls this.

(I'm not trying to do anything advanced such as dynamical defaults, using javascript.)

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to ask your question.

Answer (score 0):

A single-select date prompt with the Required property set to 'No' and the Range property set to 'Yes' will show the Earliest and Latest radio buttons and have them selected as default. When the Required property is set to 'Yes' the date prompts default to the current date. Thus, your two date prompts likely have different settings for the Required property.